# New to Ant - Problem with relative paths

Tags: eclipse, ant, path, build.xml

Please help, I'm going slightly mad!!

I'm using Eclipse-generated antfiles to build a project with dependencies, one of which has its own buildfile in a directory which is a *sibling* to the direct ancestor of the project I'm building. E.g. if my directory is **"/base/modules/clinicalcontext"**, the directory of one of the dependencies is simply **"/base/core"**.

So, the generated build.xml uses ../../core which afaik is correct. But it is not!! From the console it is apparent that Ant goes back *three* levels and not just two (it gives FileNotFound on **"/core/build.xml"**).

I tried to change the relative path to **"../core"** and much to my astonishment, this way Ant goes back by *one* level (it laments **"/base/modules/core"** being nonexistent). So how in the world I tell Ant t go back by *two* levels? I'd prefer to avoid using absolute paths, since I might have to move the project to a different machine someday.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All Ant path will be relative to your current working directory.

So, check what directory you are running your script from.

I suggest that you start using `${basedir}` to get a path relative to a location of `build.xml`.

In your case, the relative path should be constructed like this: `${basedir}/../../core`, instead of `../../core`.

The inconsistencies you encounter illustrate a point why eclipse-generated ant scripts are a good starting point, but never a good project build system.

**EDIT**. I wonder why eclipse ant generator does not insert `${basedir}` in relative paths?  Maybe you should report it as a bug.

Comment: ${basedir} is correctly set to . which is also the location of the buildfile I'm using.

Comment: Yes, but the path like this ( `../../core` ) is not relative to a basedir. `../../core` is dependent on your CWD, `${basedir}/../../core` is not.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I didn't consider that buildfiles of dependencies would not change the CWD.

Comment: I am calling an ant-task from another ant-task, but basedir seems to be relative to the build-file that started the build, not the one being executed actually...